# Redmine - Ruby - Looking for the value of a custom field

Tags: ruby, redmine, ruby-on-rails

I checked IRC for redmine and was unable to get help.
I was conflicted on weather to stick this on Superuser, ServerFault or here, but as my problem is technically programming oriented I decided to look for help here.

We have a Mercurial repository system with a layout based on projects that addresses our needs. I wrote some shell scripts which work delightfully to manage the repository and put them in correct places etc. I am trying to call these scripts and pass them parameters from Redmine. I am editing the app/controllers/projects_controller.rb (lines 75 -> 87)

I have managed to pull the project parameters and current user, but I have two custom fields I added (using the custom fields in Redmine Administration) and I am trying to access the values of these custom fields. Does anyone have any idea how I can get these?

My current working test statement is below:

```
 system "echo '#{@project.identifier}, #{User.current}' >> /tmp/rm.log"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the CustomField model. For example,

```
  # Find the first Custom Field
  cf = CustomField.first
  # Get the name
  puts cf.name
  # Find out if this Custom Field is for all projects
  cf.is_for_all?
  # If not, find out which projects are using it
  cf.projects
```

To figure this out, I just installed Redmine-1.0.0 and poked around in the source and the script/console.

Comment: I managed to work it out. I believe the above works, but I ended up just accessing the Redmine MySQL database from within a Perl script to grab the data using the identifier to find project id and then finding the custom field via an innerjoin. I'll post the code tomorrow morning for kriss, since he is invested in this question.

Answer (score 1):

```
use DBI;

$dbServer='';
$user='';
$pass='';
$ident=$ARGV[0];

my $dsn = "dbi:mysql:database=redmine;host=$dbServer;port=3306";
my $dbh = DBI->connect($dsn, "$user","$pass") or die "Can't connet to the Database: $DBI::errstr\n";
my $sth = $dbh->prepare("SELECT value FROM custom_values c INNER JOIN projects p ON c.customized_id=p.id WHERE p.identifier='$ident' LIMIT 1");
$sth -> execute();
my @row=$sth->fetchrow_array();
my $serverParams=@row[0];
```

Calling the above script (instead of echoing in the original), and then passing in the project identifier which we already have, the custom parameter can be used in whatever way nessacary. This code it to grab a single custom field (i was only using one.)

Comment: Thanks. I still have things to sort out, but it gives me a start.