# Get Redmine custom field value to a file

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, redmine

I'm trying to create a text file that contains the value of a custom field I added on redmine. I tried to get it from an SQL query in the create method of the project_controller.rb (at line 80 on redmine 1.2.0) as follows :

```
sql = Mysql.new('localhost','root','pass','bitnami_redmine')
rq = sql.query("SELECT value 
   FROM custom_values 
   INNER JOIN projects
   ON custom_values.customized_id=projects.id
   WHERE custom_values.custom_field_id=7
   AND projects.name='#{@project.name}'")
rq.each_hash { |h|
  File.open('pleasework.txt', 'w') { |myfile|
    myfile.write(h['value'])
  }
}
sql.close
```

This works fine if I test it in a separate file (with an existing project name instead of @project.name) so it may be a syntax issue but I can't find what it is. I'd also be glad to hear any other solution to get that value.

Thanks !

(there's a very similar post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3215902/redmine-ruby-looking-for-the-value-of-a-custom-field) but none of the solutions actually worked)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up simply using `params["project"]["custom_field_values"]["x"]` where `x` is the custom field's id. I still don't know why the sql query didn't work but well, this is much simpler and faster.

Answer (score 0):

First, you could use `Project.connection.query` instead of your own Mysql instance. Second, I would try to log the SQL `RAILS_DEFAULT_LOGGER.info "SELECT ..."` and check if it's ok... And the third, I would use `identifier` instead of `name`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I found another solution via the 'create' method parameters, but I will try yours to know how to make proper sql queries.